# Rails Stack too deep when using format xls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my controller method:

```
def report1
    inicio=Date.strptime(params[:start], "%d/%m/%Y") - 1.days rescue ""
    fin=Date.strptime(params[:finish], "%d/%m/%Y") - 1.days rescue ""
    @inicio=inicio
    @start=params[:start]
    @finish=params[:finish]
    @topgardenid=params[:topgarden_id]
    @projectid=params[:project_id]
    params_error=false
    if (inicio.blank?)
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Fecha inicíal no correcta o no selecionada!'
        params_error=true
    end
    if (fin.blank?)
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Fecha final no correcta o no selecionada!'
      params_error=true
    end
    if (params[:topgarden_id].blank?)
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Selecionar un Jardin'
      params_error=true
    end
    if (params[:project_id].blank?)
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Selecionar un Proyecto'
      params_error=true
    end
    if (!params_error)
    #fin=Date.parse(params[:fin]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") rescue ""
      @texts = []
      puts "INICIO [#{inicio}] FIN: [#{fin}] PROYECTO[#{params[:project_id]}] JARDÍN[#{params[:topgarden_id]}]"
      topgardens=Topgarden.find(params[:topgarden_id])
      topgardens.gardens.each do |g|
        sms=g.list_riego_dates(params[:start],params[:finish])
        if !sms.nil?
          sms.each do |s|
            @texts << s
          end

        end
      end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render 'index' }
      format.xls { headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"#{report1}\"" }
    end

  end
```

When I call the page using the format html everything is fine while when I use this link:

```
 <%= link_to "Exportar Excel", report1_path( :project_id => @projectid, :topgarden_id => @topgardenid, :start => @start, :finish => @finish,   :format => "xls"), :class =>"vvbutton btn btn-success" %>
```

I got this rails error:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:79
```

It seems that the method got called infinite times but I can't understand why this happen just in case format xls is triggered.

On other controllers I'm using the xls format the same way but did not get any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line tries to interpolate `report1` into a string. Since `report1` is the name of your method, it calls it until you get a SystemStackError.

```
format.xls { headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"#{report1}\"" }
```